# Trouble with making a makefile

Tags: c, makefile

So I made a program that contains the files header.h, main.c, printd.c and printd.h. I've been trying to create a Makefile to compile it all together but I'm having trouble understanding it.

**header.h**

```
#ifndef SPOVAJA1_HEADER_H
#define SPOVAJA1_HEADER_H
typedef struct {
    int size;
    char* tag[3][3];
    char* text[3][128];
} header;
#endif //SPOVAJA1_HEADER_H
```

**printd.h**

```
#ifndef SPOVAJA1_PRINTD_H
#define SPOVAJA1_PRINTD_H

#include "header.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printd(header* format, int i, char* niz);
#endif //SPOVAJA1_PRINTD_H
```

**printd.c**

```
//
// Created by Admin on 9. 03. 2021.
//

#include "printd.h"
void printd(header* format, int i, char* niz){

   char *messageOutput;

   messageOutput = (char *) malloc(sizeof(niz) + 2*sizeof(char*) +sizeof(format->text[i][0]));
   strcpy(messageOutput, format->text[i][0]);
   strcat(messageOutput, niz);

   printf("%s", messageOutput);
   free(messageOutput);
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "header.h"
#include "printd.h"

header format = {
       .size = 3,
       .tag[0] = "INF",
       .tag[1] = "DBG",
       .tag[2] = "ERR",
       .text[0] = "INFO: ",
       .text[1] = "DEBUG: ",
       .text[2] = "ERROR: "
};
int main() {
   printd(&format, 2, "oops, error");
   return 0;
}
```

I used CLion to generate the function and header files on windows. Now I wanted to make my own Makefile to run it on Linux and I can't seem to get it right.

**Makefile**

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-m32 

all: main printd

demo_printd: main.c printd.c
   gcc -o main main.c printd.c -I

clean: 
   rm demo_printd
```

Comment: `demo_printd` is not a good target. It's generally recommended that the target name match the output file, so you'd better have `gcc -o demo_printd ...`.

Comment: Can you also add the output of `make` please ?

Comment: Also a dangling `-I` makes little sense - what include directory do you want to add?

Comment: What name do you want the executable to have, `main` or `demo_printd`?

Comment: your rules aren't making sense to me, when you run make it will look at ```all``` and try to look for ```main``` and ```printd``` and since those don't exist it will try to make them, now as far as I know there are no implicit rules for files without extensions so it will probably tell you about non-existent rules.

to fix it just change it to:
```all: demo_printd```

Comment: @Beta I want it to have demo_printd, and to answer @limserhane I get cc -m32     main.c   -o main
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccJZvabH.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `printd'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: main] Error 1

Comment: I guess I was wrong, it found an implicit rule but it still didn't work cause in this compile command the linker doesn't know about `printd.c`, again, the fix that I gave should remedy this, you should also include a ```$(CFLAGS)``` in the ```gcc``` call.

Comment: @Cufox Run `make -p` without a Makefile. There *is* an implicit rule for `%: %.c` with command being `$(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@`

Comment: @iBug cheers! didn't know I could do that :> this will sure come in handy.

Comment: @Cufox Just FYI, They're all documented on [the GNU website here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to understand that makefile so tather than just rewrite your makefile for you, I'll try to help you understand it.  Let's look at it:

```
 CC=gcc
 CFLAGS=-m32
```

Here you're setting two variables `CC` and `CFLAGS`.  Why?  What is the goal of setting these variables?

```
all: main printd
```

Here you're telling make that there's a target `all` and it depends on two targets `main` and `printd`.  Why?  What do you expect this to do?

```
demo_printd: main.c printd.c
```

Here you are saying that a target `demo_printd` depends on two files `main.c` and `printd.c`, which is fine.  However:

```
gcc -o main main.c printd.c -I
```

What does this compile line do?  What output file does it generate?  If you type that into your shell prompt (which is basically what make is going to do, except in an automated way) what happens?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `makefile` to make the minimum number of compilations then you need to first think what are your dependencies.

- Your executable is called `demo_printd`, which should depend on the object files (just linked only) `main.o` and `printd.o` (in case one of these files is modified, you should recreate the program by linking

```
cc -o demo_printd main.o printd.o
```

- `Main.o` depends on `main.c`, `header.h` and `printd.h` (if any of these files gets modified, you need to compile main)  with:

```
cc -c main.c
```

- and `printd.c` depends on `printd.h` only.  So in case you change `printd.h` or `printd.c` then `printd.c` needs to be recompiled.

```
cc -c printd.c
```

- there's a `#include <header.h>` in `printd.h` that makes that everything that depends on `printd.h` will also need recompiling if `header.h` is modified, so anything that depends on `printd.h` will also depend on `header.h`.

So we have already all the data necessary to build our rule set.  The rules will be:

- `demo_printd: main.o printd.o`.  To handle this rule, we execute the linker.
- `main.o: main.c header.h printd.h`.  To handle this rule, we recompile `main.c`.
- `printd.o: printd.c printd.h header.h` (remember that everything that depends on `printd.h` also depends on `header.h`).  This means recompiling `printd.c`.

So our minimum `Makefile` should be:

```
demo_printd: main.o printd.o
    cc -o demo_printd main.o printd.o
main.o: main.c header.h printd.h
    cc -c main.c
printd.o: printd.c printd.h header.h
    cc -c printd.c
```

Now, you'll see that the include files are dependencies in all the compilations, so as their names are repeated, we can store the list of includes in a makefile variable... this also happens with the object files list, so we can rearrange this into (we will introduce some very useful variables here):

```
demo_printd_objs = main.o printd.o
headers = printd.h header.h

demo_printd: $(demo_printd_objs)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o demo_printd $(demo_printd_objs)
main.o: main.c $(headers)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c
printd.o: printd.c $(headers)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c printd.c
```

And this is only the beginning.  For a full text on using `make` I recommend you to continue reading on make, with some very good online references (one is the [GNU MAKE textinfo documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/), that you can also get straight from your linux system, or the book on BSD's `pmake`, which you can get from the [FreeBSD.Org site](https://docs.freebsd.org/doc/5.5-RELEASE/usr/share/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/pmake/)